# SOAP node returns error Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I'm  trying to write a client for russian post to get track. It uses SOAP WSDL.
I'm to get at least client object.

```
 'use strict'
let soap=require('soap'),
url = 'https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?wsdl',
argums={}

soap.createClient(url,argums,function(err, client){
    console.log(client) 
})
```

but it returns error

```
Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
/home/st.cremer/Сайты/get-posts/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:481
    this.element = schema.elements[nsName.name];
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
```

Can anyone explain what does it meand what should request look like?

Answer (score 7):

**Solved**. Workaround of issue.
First instead of their .wsdl file I use modified original wsdl file and store it locally.

**workaround of xml file** Fixed it by adding into schema targetnNamespace parameter.

```
<definitions ... xmlns:myns="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory">
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=2"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=3"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=4"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=5"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=6"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getOperationHistory" targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getOperationHistory"/>
</message>
```

---

**Original wsdl code part**

```
    <types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data" schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data" schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=2"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=3"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data" schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=4"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data" schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=5"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory" schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=6"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getOperationHistory">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getOperationHistory"/>
</message>
```

now to use our wsdl file:

```
var SoapClient = require('soap');
var options = {
    'trace': 1,
    "overrideRootElement": {
        "namespace": "myns",
        "xmlnsAttributes": [{
            "name": "xmlns:ns2",
            "value": "http://russianpost.org/operationhistory"
        }]
    },
    forceSoap12Headers: true,
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'soap_version': 2
};
SoapClient.createClient('./local_wsdl.xml', options, function (err, client) {
    client.getOperationHistory(
        {
        'ns1:OperationHistoryRequest': {
            'ns1:Barcode': trackValue,
            'ns1:MessageType': 0,
            'ns1:Language': 'RUS',
        },
        'ns1:AuthorizationHeader': {
            'ns1:login': login,
            'ns1:password': password,
        },
    },
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

            return;
        }

        console.log(result.OperationHistoryData);
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: works for my only adding the "targetNamespace=" to the wsdl and save a local copy of that in the root path of the app

Comment: Firts open in my browser the wsdl url and save as wsdl file, after I modify in a text editor thats it.

Comment: Hi how update soap server "wsdl file" from another server when i can't access server ?

Comment: @SoheilTayyeb if you can access the "wsdl file" via a web browser, just save the file on your computer and update it.

Comment: This works so +1, but see my answer below for a solution that doesn't require keeping a local copy of the wsdl.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by defined only one schema tag, example:

From:

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=2"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=3"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=4"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=5"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=6"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

To:

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=1"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=2"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=3"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=4"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=5"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory"
                    schemaLocation="https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34?xsd=6"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Regards.

Comment: How did you choose which namespace to wrap all of it? ("http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data" in your case)

Answer (score 2):

While the above top solution does work, it's a poor solution since it defeats the whole purpose of WSDLs. SoapUI works fine with the service I'm using and this tool should be able to as well.

I ended up solving this by updating the node-soap code in `node_modules\soap\lib\wsdl\elements.js` by adding the following lines after line 826: `var targetNamespace = child.$targetNamespace;`:

```
if (!targetNamespace && child.includes && child.includes.length === 1) {
    targetNamespace = child.includes[0].namespace;
}
```

This works if you have a schema element where the only child is an import element (see example below). May try to get a PR approved if the maintainer is up for it.

Example:

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://schema.core.datamodel.fs.documentum.emc.com/" schemaLocation="ObjectService_schema1.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://rt.fs.documentum.emc.com/" schemaLocation="ObjectService_schema2.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

See git repo for original TS code: [https://github.com/.../node-soap/.../elements.ts#L826](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/wsdl/elements.ts#L826)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but haven't solved it.

Version: 
"soap": "^0.19.0"

```
    Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
/Users/andreas/scm/todoListApi/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:481
    this.element = schema.elements[nsName.name];
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefinedTarget-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!
```

Update: the WSDL does not contain targetNamespace. How to work around that? Can I use the WSDL Options somehow?

Comment: the 'schema' tags have some child tags inside, with attribute 'namespace'