# Target namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I'm trying to use the SOAP provided by this URL 'https://secure.umweltbundesamt.at/eras/erasapi?wsdl'. 
So my node code is really simple:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var apiWSDL = 'https://secure.umweltbundesamt.at/eras/erasapi?wsdl';
soap.createClient(apiWSDL,options,  function(err, client) {
            if(err) throw new Error(err);
        })
```

But I'm getting

> Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema!

I think for some reason soap doesn´t like 'tns' from the schema but I don't know why or how to solve it.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem? i'm facing it too

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761898/800198 for a potential solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SOAP node returns error Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634842/soap-node-returns-error-target-namespace-undefined-already-in-use-by-another-s)

Comment: yes, that solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML described by the service URL is missing 'targetNamespace' attribute in some 'schema' tags.

Download the XML file from the URL and add 'targetNamespace' manually to all 'schema' tags. And make client from path to local file instead of http URL.

Related answer: [SOAP node returns error Target-Namespace "undefined" already in use by another Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634842/soap-node-returns-error-target-namespace-undefined-already-in-use-by-another-s)